# Storing Dictionary Item as Class Instance - Object Doesn't Support This Property or Method

Tags: excel, vba

I have simple VBA dictionary.  The Key is a string, the Item a custom class (that contains simple properties, and a few functions).

I'm iterating through my dictionary, trying to call one of the functions of each class instance (cNewClass) in the dictionary.   I'm struggling here:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim nt As New cNewClass
a = dict.Items
For i = 0 To dict.Count - 1
     nt = a(i)
Next i
```

At the line:

```
 nt = a(i)
```

I get the error: "Object doesn't support this property or method".

[Edit: Tried this, didn't work]  Could I instead do something like?:

```
For i = 0 To dict.Count - 1
    a(i).RunMethod(Args)
Next i
```

Thanks - KC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As you noticed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36724689/1188513), you need to use the `Set` keyword to assign object references.

> ```
> Dim i As Integer
> Dim nt As New cNewClass
> a = dict.Items
> For i = 0 To dict.Count - 1
>      Set nt = a(i)
> Next i
> ```

However I need to warn you about a nasty gotcha here: `As New cNewClass` is changing the behavior of `nt`, and this may or may not interfere, but still I *have* to warn you about it:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim c As New Collection
    c.Add "Foo"
    Set c = Nothing
    c.Add "Bar" 'you'd think this would blow up because 'c' is Nothing, right? Think again!
End Sub
```

When a local object variable is declared `As New`, VBA keeps the reference alive no matter what, which *may* introduce undesired or unexpected behavior.

You're not using the reference you're declaring `nt` with - just let go of the `New` keyword there:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim nt As cNewClass
a = dict.Items
For i = 0 To dict.Count - 1
     Set nt = a(i)
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer - use "SET"

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim nt As New cNewClass
a = dict.Items
For i = 0 To dict.Count - 1
     Set nt = a(i)
Next i
```